# Do expired eggs float in water?

Tags: nutrition

I was going back through the app that gave us the [Wendy question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4081/was-the-name-wendy-created-for-peter-pan), when I found this:

> Eggs sink in water when they are fresh
>   and float when expired

I also found this advice:

> Fresh eggs will sink to the bottom of
>   the bowl and lie on their sides. 
>   Slightly older eggs (about one week)
>   will lie on the bottom but bob
>   slightly.  If the egg balances on its
>   smallest end, with the large end
>   reaching for the sky, it's probably
>   around three weeks old.  Eggs that
>   float at the surface are bad and
>   should not be consumed. [source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080723104108AAWeyzl)

Is any of this validated by scientific evidence, or is it just an old wives' tale?

Comment: Salt or fresh water?

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure, no one specified. I'm assuming fresh, but obviously the salt concentration of the water would make a difference with regard to buoyancy of an object.

Comment: Anecdotal: I just put an egg in my sink that expired 25 days ago.  It didn't float, but balanced on its little end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An egg absorbs air through the shell and discard water/vapor. Old eggs will have enough air to float.

> As the egg ages, moisture and carbon
>   dioxide leave through the pores of the
>   shell, air enters to replace them and
>   the air cell becomes larger.
>
> An air cell (space) forms when the
>   contents of the egg cool and contract
>   after the egg is laid. The air cell
>   usually rests between the outer and
>   inner membranes at the egg’s larger
>   end.

See [this page](http://www.edinformatics.com/math_science/science_of_cooking/how_fresh_is_that_egg.htm) for more info.

Comment: In other words, when eggs float it is an indicator that they've lost moisture. This is not a reliable indicator for whether the egg is safe to eat or not. Storing the egg in a drier environment will cause them to start floating earlier and vice versa.

Comment: @Agrajag: Reliable, no. But it helps to set reasonable expectations before cracking it open. :)